# Toggle Checkbox True / False in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, boolean

**I need to toggle boolean value through one checkbox**

Right now I have two checkboxes one set to true and the other set to false

When someone clicks on wither button it set an event on the submit button to submit the new value.

```
<%= form_with(model: @project, local: true) do |form| %>
<div>
    <div id="info_false">
        <%= label :access_rights, "Pending", value: false %>
        <%= form.radio_button :build_one, false, :checked => true, :value => false, id: "build_one_1" %>
    </div>
    <div id="info_true">
        <%= label :access_rights, "Completed", value: true %>
        <%= form.radio_button :build_one, true, :value => true, id: "build_one_2" %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= form.submit id: "build_one", :style => "visibility:hidden;", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I need to toggle a boolean value through one checkbox - right now I have two checkboxes one set to true and one set to false. So when the one checkbox is not checked it will be false and when checked it will be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are `radio` buttons not `checkboxes`, I'm not sure if I understand what you are looking for but you can toggle between `true` or `false` values for radio buttons in a simple way

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/ff9ccqx5/1/

Comment: Oh sorry about that I have checkboxes set in another section of the page. Fiddle looks like it will do the job thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help, would you mind accepting the answer if it helped you?